# wpa_supplicant.conf second network not saved when using wpa_cli

Tags: networking, wpa-supplicant

On multiple RPis I have the same issue - once I have a `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` with a single network configured, using `wpa_cli` to *add* a network does not update the configuration file after using `save_config` - this return `OK` there is no failure?

When changing properties of the existing network (`0`) followed by `save_config` then `wpa_supplicant.conf` is modified with those changed. However, the second network is not added.

For reference, here is the configuration:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
        ssid="NetworkSSID"
        psk=xxxxxxxxxxxx
}
```

Then issuing the following series of `wpa_cli` actions:

```
$ wpa_cli

wpa_cli v2.8-devel
Copyright (c) 2004-2019, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.


Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0'

Interactive mode

> add_network 
1
> set_network 1 ssid "MyNewNetwork"
OK
> set_network 1 password "xxxxxxxxxx"
OK
> enable_network 1
OK

## Adding this for demonstration

> set_network 0 priority 10
OK

## end of demo

> save_config 
OK
> quit
```

The modified `wpa_supplicant.conf` is now...

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
        ssid="NetworkSSID"
        psk=xxxxxxxxxxxx
        priority=10
}
```

The configuration was clearly updated, but the new network (`1`) is not added.

I'm building some configuration tooling, so using dbus to communicate with `wpa_supplicant` (indirectly). It's the same there as using the interactive CLI. What am I missing?

This is all being done as root, and root (and `pi`) are part of the `netdev` group. The configuration is being updated, just a new network is not being persisted in the `wpa_supplicant.conf` so not persisted on reboot.

Comment: What OS? What are you attempting to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same error here is how it worked for me:

Remove your network conf in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, it must look like this :

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US
```

Ensure you have no instance of wpa_supplicant and start wpa_supplicant:

```
sudo killall wpa_supplicant
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Remove all registered networks with wpa_cli:

```
~$ sudo wpa_cli
> remove_network 0
OK
> remove_network 1
OK 
> remove_network 2
OK
> remove_network X
FAIL
```

When the `remove_network` command return `FAIL`, you have no registered network, then :

```
> add_network
0
> set_network 0 ssid "wifi1"
OK
> set_network 0 psk "PASSWORD"
OK
> add_network
1 
> set_network 1 ssid "wifi2"
OK
> set_network 1 psk "PASSWORD"
OK
> save_config
> quit
```

Now you have two networks in your `wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: I happened on the same solution, by accidentally (not sure how) saving a configuration with no networks. It started working after that too.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this too, and the key here seems to be that you are using

```
set_network 1 password "xxxxxxxxxx"
```

like this, the wpa_cli does not save the network (despite reporting OK). What you need to do is to set the password using

```
set_network 1 psk "xxxxxxxxxx"
```

The `save_config` will now correctly add the network.